# Innested async call Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this function that calls a service to get data through api. I would like after the first call, if result is equal to 50, another call is made with updated offset. But this doesn't work. It doesn't go into the arrow function:

```
result: any[] = []

   async getData(v) {
      await this.gs.getMaxGifs(v, this.offset).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.result.push(...response.data);
      this.offset += 50;
      if (this.result.length % 50 == 0) {
          console.log('DENTRO')
          async () => {
            await this.gs.getMaxGifs(v, this.offset).subscribe((response: any) => {
              console.log('DENTRO22222')
            })
            this.result.push(...response.data);
            this.offset += 50;
          }
      }
      console.log(this.result.length)
    });
  }
```

[image]

When this then works, I want to replace the if with the while. If I insert it now it goes into an infinite loop

Comment: why dont you do it like this,

`   async getData(v) {
      await this.gs.getMaxGifs(v, this.offset).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.result.push(...response.data);
      this.offset += 50;
      if (this.result.length % 50 == 0) {
          console.log('DENTRO')
          this.getData(v);
      }
      console.log(this.result.length)
    });`

do a recursive call.

Comment: Perfect @DeepakJha , it works!!! 2 hours racking my brain when the solution was simpler =) . Thank you very much

Comment: let me put this in answer then :) please accept it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented it worked for sirss,

```
async getData(v) { 
await this.gs.getMaxGifs(v, this.offset).subscribe((response: any) => { this.result.push(...response.data); 
this.offset += 50; if (this.result.length % 50 == 0) { 
console.log('DENTRO');
this.getData(v); 
} 
console.log(this.result.length) });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result: any[] = []

 getData(v) {
  this.gs.getMaxGifs(v, 
   this.offset).subscribe((response: any) => {
  this.result.push(...response.data);
  this.offset += 50;
  if (this.result.length % 50 == 0) {
      console.log('DENTRO')
      
        this.gs.getMaxGifs(v, this.offset).subscribe((response: any) => {
          console.log('DENTRO22222')
        
        this.result.push(...response.data);
        this.offset += 50;
      }
  }
  console.log(this.result.length)
});
}
```

Or if you want to do this recuresive you can do it like this

```
    result: any[] = []

 getData(v) {
  this.gs.getMaxGifs(v, 
   this.offset).subscribe((response: any) => {
  this.result.push(...response.data);
  this.offset += 50;
  if (this.result.length % 50 == 0) {
      this.getData(v)
  }
  console.log(this.result.length)
});
}
```